# Sumproduct with countifs returning 0

Tags: excel, formula, sumproduct

I have a sheet with a list of users (column A). In my dataset I have rows with the datetime (AD), extracted date(AE), and user for that datetime instance(AF).

I'm trying to write a formula that returns a count of unique dates for a user.

I've tried a few formulas, and gotten #NAME and #VALUE errors. This is my latest attempt, which is returning 0 as a count. I've hit Google and looked up a few other approaches to this, none have worked yet.

The closest I've gotten is my 0 (zero) return code, which is:

```
=Sumproduct(((AF:AF=A2))/CountIfs(AF:AF,AF:AF&",AE:AE,AE:AE&""))
```

So this should be grabbing the user from A2, finding all instances of that user in AF, then searching the Dates in AE to count how many unique dates are there for that user. But I get a 0 (zero) as a returned value.

Any thoughts?

Comment: limit the ranges to the dataset only and not the full column.

Comment: Also, you are missing a `"` in the formula

Comment: Wouldn't a pivot table be helpfull in your case?

Comment: Thanks Scott. I will try that. When I was typing up my question I missed typing the other ". It is there in my workbook.

Comment: JvdV, I'm using this as part of a "scorecard" for productivity. I'm trying to write everything in formulas so I can paste in the raw data and it will populate. This is my 'test sheet'. Once this formula is figured out, the references will point to my raw data sheet, instead of cluttering up the margins of the "scorecard".

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to use PivotTables, you might want to try the following:

[image]

Formula in `AI2`:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF($A$2:$A$10=AH2,MATCH($AE$2:$AE$10,$AE$2:$AE$10,0)),ROW($AE$2:$AE$10)-ROW($AE$2)+1)>0))
```

> ***Note:*** It's an array formula and needs to be entered through: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

The answer is based on [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-text-values-with-criteria) article.

Comment: Thanks everyone! After trying to limit the cell range, I was still getting 0. So I found one of the issues. I was using a formula to extract the date from the date-time. Even though the cell gave the correct date, it appears my counting-formula was not reading the output of that date-split formula. I went and copied the dates as 'text only', and though the query took A LOT of time to process (58K rows), it did finally work. I'll have to go back to the report database the raw data is pulled out of and see if it can create that date column.

Comment: JvdV, thank you for that formula! That's one of the ones I had tried, but was getting a #value or #name error on (I don't recall which). I may have not entered it as an array formula. I will try that next. Thanks!

Comment: @MathematicalFawkes, no worries. Did it work for you now?